# How to properly use recursion in this (simple) python procedure?

Tags: python, data-structures, recursion

guys, I wrote a function to test if two inputs (a and b) have the same data structure, this way:

```
print same_structure([1, 0, 1], [a, b, c])
#>>> True
#print same_structure([1, [0], 1], [2, 5, 3])
>>> False
#print same_structure([1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', 'e']]]])
>>> True  
#print same_structure([1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]], ['a', ['b', ['c', ['de']]]])
>>> False
```

This function has (in my implementation) to use recursion. I'm very beginner in recursion and I still have difficulty on thinking recursively. In addition, to avoid cheating the answer, I want to use my own (messy) code and through it learn to use the recursive call (using this code line: 'same_structure return (a [i], b [e])' properly). Could someone show how to properly use the recursion in code below?
Thanks in advance for any help!!!

```
def is_list(p):
return isinstance(p, list)

def same_structure(a,b):
    if not is_list(a) and not is_list(b):
        print '#1'
        return True
    else:
        if is_list(a) and is_list(b):
            print '#2'
            if len(a) != len(b):
                print '#3'
                return False
            if len(a) == len(b):
                print '#4'
                for e in range(len(a)):
                    print 'e = ', e, 'a[e]= ', a[e], 'b[e]=', b[e]
                    return same_structure(a[e], b[e])           
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
def same_structure(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list) and len(a) == len(b):
        return all(same_structure(A, B) for A, B in zip(a, b))
    return (not isinstance(a, list) and not isinstance(b, list))
```

When writing recursive functions, you first need to come up with the base case, where you just return a value instead of calling any recursion.  The base case here is one of the following conditions:

- `a` is a list and `b` isn't, or vice-versa: return False
- `a` and `b` are both lists, but they have different lengths: return False
- neither `a` or `b` are lists: return True

If `a` and `b` are both lists and they have the same length, we need to now check each element of these lists recursively.  `zip(a, b)` provides a convenient way to iterate over the elements from each list together, and if the result of `same_structure()` is False for any two sub-elements, we want the entire function to return False.  This is why `all()` is used, if you are unfamiliar with `all()` it is equivalent (but more efficient) to the following loop:

```
match = True
for A, B in zip(a, b):
    if not same_structure(A, B):
        match = False
        break
return match
```

Here is how you could rewrite your function without changing too much, the logic is actually very similar to my solution, but just below the `print '#4'` you were returning from that loop too early:

```
def same_structure(a,b):
    if not is_list(a) and not is_list(b):
        print '#1'
        return True
    else:
        if is_list(a) and is_list(b):
            print '#2'
            if len(a) != len(b):
                print '#3'
                return False
            if len(a) == len(b):
                print '#4'
                for e in range(len(a)):
                    print 'e = ', e, 'a[e]= ', a[e], 'b[e]=', b[e]
                    if not same_structure(a[e], b[e]):
                        return False
                return True        
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Hi, @F.J! Your code is by far better than mine (THANKS!). But I'm not suppose to use zip() or all() in this hw. In addition, to avoid cheating the answer, I want to take my own (messy) code and through it, learn HOW to use the recursive call (fixing this code line 'same_structure return (a [i], b [e])').

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice I made an edit about 10 minutes ago which has an edited version of your function that should work, while still following those requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, it works with all your examples and it's written in a recursive, functional-programming style but without using `zip`, `all`, etc. only slices to reduce the size of the list at each step:

```
def same_structure(a, b):
    if a == [] or b == []:
        return a == b
    elif is_list(a[0]) != is_list(b[0]):
        return False
    elif not is_list(a[0]):
        return same_structure(a[1:], b[1:])
    else:
        return same_structure(a[0], b[0]) and same_structure(a[1:], b[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only doing the first recursive call, since you're returning right away.

If I understood what you want to do, you need to is call same_structure with the sub-element, and check it's return value (not Return it immediately). If the result of any of the calls is false, return false, otherwise, return true.